# head to/ towards/for

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

If there are no differences between them, so I suppose these sentences are correct:

> I'm heading the door/car/barbershop.
>
> I'm heading for the door/car/barbershop.
>
> I'm heading to the door/car/barbershop.
>
> I'm heading towards the door/car/barbershop.

Are these sentences interchangeable?

Comment: You can't *head the door*. The other three sentences are fine. All three prepositions can be used after *heading*.

Comment: But what about heading the car? is it correct?

Comment: No, it's wrong. You can head a ball (where this means to hit it with your head) and *head the class* (which means to be the top student) but when *head* means *to go in the direction of*, it requires a preposition. An exception might be such expressions as *heading home* and *heading back*..

Comment: Ok, when talking about directions, you said it needs a preposition, but what can you say about "heading home"? I hear this phrase very often.

Comment: As I illustrated, there are a number of such expressions. But doors, cars and barber shops are not among them. *Heading home* is shorthand for *heading for home* and *back* is an adverb, not a noun. There are other examples such as *head upwards*.

Comment: For more information about "heading home," see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/prepositions-used-with-home. @RonaldSole, I'm tagging you in case you would like a reference for other users in the future.

Comment: By the way, the sentences are all fine as Ronald Sole says; however, if you are asking if are interchangeable, they are not. They would all be used in slightly different situations; interestingly enough, because they are slightly different prepositions :).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm heading the door/car/barbershop.

This version isn't correct. As a commenter said, you can't *head a door*. Note that head *is* a verb, though. You can *head a soccer ball* for instance.

> I'm heading for the door/car/barbershop.

This version is correct. It has slightly more urgency than the example below. For example, you might say a soccer player is *heading for the ball*, because they are in a hurry to get there.

> I'm heading to the door/car/barbershop.

This version is correct. It implies a longer distance than the other versions. It makes more sense to use this version if your car is parked 3 blocks away, as opposed to in your garage, for example. However, it works fine in all scenarios.

> I'm heading towards the door/car/barbershop.

This version is correct. You shouldn't use this version, however, unless you are *currently in transit*. For example, if you were in your house, planning to go to the barbershop, you wouldn't say you're *heading towards the barbershop*. But if you're in your car and someone asks you where you're going, it would make sense to say you're *heading towards the barbershop.*

Answer (score 0):

> I am heading to/for/toward(s) the door/car/barbershop.

All the above prepositions mean much the same.

[The Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=headed+to%2Cheaded+for%2Cheaded+toward%2Cheaded+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheaded%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20toward%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheaded%20towards%3B%2Cc0) shows that the preposition "for" is used at least ten times more frequently in comparison with the others, the preposition "towards" being used the rarest.

Note: *Without* a preposition the verb "to head" meaning "to go" can be used very restrictedly as, for example, in "to head *north/northwards*" or, as was suggested in comments, *"upwards"* or *"inland"*, etc.